# Predict the number of iterations required - iterated weighted average

Tags: python, math

Pardon me but I could find a better title. Please look at this super-simple Python program:

```
x = start = 1.0
target = 0.1

coeff = 0.999

for c in range(100000):

    print('{:5d} {:f}'.format(c, x))
    if abs(target - x) < abs((x - start) * 0.01):
        break

    x = x * coeff + target * (1 - coeff)
```

Brief explaination: this program moves `x` towards `target` calculating iteratively the weighted average of `x` and `target` with `coeff` as weight. It stops when `x` reaches the 1% of the initial difference.

The number of iterations remains the same no matter the initial value of `x` and `target`.

How can I set `coeff` in order to predict how many iterations will take place?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the goal here. What do you mean by "set coeff to predict how many iterations will take place?"

Comment: I think he means if there is a function of coeff which maps to the number of iterations needed

Comment: @RyanLim: my guess is that he wants to know how many iterations the loop will run, given the value of `start`, `target`, and `coeff`, which requires solving an inequality polynomial in `coeff` in the form `k0 * start * coeff^n + target * (k1 * coeff^n + k2 * coeff^(n-1) + ... + kn) < k`

Comment: With some algebra it can be shown that value of `x` after `n` iterations is given by `x_val = lambda n: start*(coeff**n) + target*(1-coeff)*(sum(coeff**i for i in range(n)))`. You need to  find the minimum n that solves your condition.

Comment: I mean that when coeff is 0.999 the iterations are 4613. I'm looking for the formula to get 0.999 from 4613. Also, there's some kind of logarithmic relation: 0.99 -> 460, 0.999 -> 4613, 0.9999 -> 46149.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make this a function, `f`.

`f(0)` is the initial value (`start`, in this case `1.0`).

`f(x) = f(x - 1) * c + T * (1 - c)`.

(So `f(1)` is the next value of x, `f(2)` is the one after that, and so on. We want to find the value of `x` where `|T - f(x)| < 0.01 * |f(0) - f(x)|`)

So let's rewrite `f(x)` to be linear:

```
f(x) = f(x - 1) * c + T * (1 - c)
     = (f(x - 2) * c + T * (1 - c)) * c + T * (1 - c)
     = (f(x - 2) * c ** 2 + T * c * (1 - c)) + T * (1 - c)
     = ((f(x - 3) * c + T * (1 - c)) * c ** 2 + T * c * (1 - c)) + T * (1 - c)
     = f(x - 3) * c ** 3 + T * c ** 2 * (1 - c) + T * c * (1 - c) + T * (1 - c)

     = f(0) * c ** x + T * c ** (x - 1) * (1 - c) + T * c ** (x - 2) * (1 - c) + ... + T * c * (1 - c) + T * (1 - c)

     = f(0) * c ** x + (T * (1 - c)) [(sum r = 0 to x - 1) (c ** r)]
  # Summation of a geometric series
     = f(0) * c ** x + (T * (1 - c)) ((1 - c ** x) / (1 - c))
     = f(0) * c ** x + T (1 - c ** x)
```

So, the nth value of x will be `start * c ** n + target * (1 - c ** n)`.

We want:

```
|T - f(x)| < 0.01 * |f(0) - f(x)|
|T - f(0) * c ** x - T (1 - c ** x)| < 0.01 * |f(0) - f(0) * c ** x - T (1 - c ** x)|
|(c ** x) * T - (c ** x) f(0)| < 0.01 * |(1 - c ** x) * f(0) - (1 - c ** x) * T|
(c ** x) * |T - f(0)| < 0.01 * (1 - c ** x) * |T - f(0)|
c ** x < 0.01 * (1 - c ** x)
c ** x < 0.01 - 0.01 * c ** x
1.01 * c ** x < 0.01
c ** x < 1 / 101
x < log (1 / 101) / log c
```

(I somehow ended up with `x <` when it should be `x >`, but it gives the correct answer. With `c = 0.999`, `x > 4612.8`, and it terminates on step `4613`).

In the end, it is independant of `start` and `target`.

Also, for a general percentage difference of `p`,

```
c ** x > p * (1 - c ** x)
c ** x > p - p c ** x
(1 + p) c ** x > p
c ** x > p / (1 + p)
x > log (p / (1 + p)) / log c
```

So for a coefficient of `c`, there will be `log (1 / 101) / log c` steps.

If you have the number of steps you want, call it `I`, you have

```
I = log_c(1 / 101)
c ** I = 1 / 101
c = (1 / 101) ** (1 / I)
```

So `c` should be set to the `I`th root of `1 / 101`.

Comment: I AM SINCERELY IMPRESSED. Thanks 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Your code reduces the distance between x and the target by a factor of `coeff` in each execution of the loop. Thus, if `start` is greater than `target`, we get the formula

```
target - x = (x - start) * coeff ** c
```

where `c` is the number of loops we have done.

Your ending criterion is (again, if `start` is greater than `target`),

```
x - target < (start - x) * 0.01
```

Solving for `x` by algebra we get

```
x > (target + 0.01 * s) / (1 + 0.01)
```

Substituting that into our first expression and simplifying a bit makes both `start` and `target` drop out of the inequality--now you see why those values did not matter--and we get

```
0.01 / (1 + 0.01) < coeff ** c
```

Solving for `c` we get

```
c > log(0.01 / (1 + 0.01), coeff)
```

So the final answer for the number of loops is

```
ceil(log(0.01 / (1 + 0.01), coeff))
```

or alternatively, if you do not like logarithms to an arbitrary base,

```
ceil(log(0.01 / (1 + 0.01)) / log(coeff))
```

You could replace that first logarithm in that last expression with its result, but I left it that way to see what different result you would get if you change the constant in your end criterion away from `0.01`.

The result of that expression in your particular case is

```
4613
```

which is correct. Note that both the `ceil` and `log` function are in Python's `math` unit, so remember to import those functions before doing that calculation. Also note that Python's floating point calculations are not exact, so your actual number of loops may differ from that by one, if you change the values of `coeff` or of `0.01`.